# Как сделать что бы функция клик по документу выполнялся только после открытия окна поиска

Tags: javascript, jquery

Народ помоги пожалуйста!!!

Задумка такая, что меню поиска должно скрываться если кликнул не по нему,а мимо куда-то по странице.

Как сделать что бы клик по веб документу "$(document).mouseup" срабатывал только если окно поиска открыто.

Сейчас $(document).mouseup срабатывает каждый раз когда кликаешь по документу и и-за этого возникает баг, если кликнуть по странице и сразу кликнуть по кнопке поиска,то просто расширяется сам блок, но не срабатывают анимации.

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('.searchBtn').click(function(){
        $('.menu_nav').hide();
        $('.search_input').show();  
        $('.closeBtn').show();
        $('.menu_search').animate({'width':'80%'},500);
     });
    });

 $('.closeBtn').click(function(){
    $('.menu_search').animate({'width':'120'},300,function(){
        $('.search_input').hide();
        $('.closeBtn').hide();
        $('.search_input').val("");
        if($(window).width() > 768){
            $('.menu_nav').show(300);  
        };
    });
});



$(document).mouseup(function (e){ // событие клика по веб-документу
        var div = $(".searchBtn, .search_input, .shopBtn, .menu_search"); // тут указываем ID элементов исключений
        if (!div.is(e.target)
        && div.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            $('.menu_search').animate({'width':'120'},300,function(){
            $('.search_input').hide();
            $('.closeBtn').hide();
            $('.search_input').val("");
                if($(window).width() > 768){
                    $('.menu_nav').show(300);  
                }; 
            });           
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="menu">

    <ul class="menu_nav">
        <li>about</li>
        <li>service</li>
        <li>work</li>
        <li>blog</li>
        <li>contact</li>
  </ul>

    <div class="menu_search">
        <input type="search" class="search_input" placeholder="Поиск по сайту" value="">
        <i class="fas fa-times closeBtn"></i>
        <i class="far fa-search searchBtn"></i>
        <i class="far fa-shopping-cart shopBtn"></i>
    </div>  

</div>
```

Вот так должно работать [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот баг, если кликнуть быстро на странице, а потом на поиск.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что должно проверить условие !div.is(e.target)&& div.has(e.target).length === 0 ?  Я всегда получаю true, при каких обстоятельствах должен быть false?

Comment: Ох я когда-то давно кусок этого кода спер. и так в оригинале было такое  ////////////////    jQuery(function($){
 $(document).mouseup(function (e){ // событие клика по веб-документу или бургеру
  var div = $(".menu_active, .menu-link"); // тут указываем ID элемента
  if (!div.is(e.target) // если клик был не по нашему блоку
      && div.has(e.target).length === 0) { 
   menu.removeClass('menu_active');
   link.removeClass('menu-link_active');
 }
 });
});

Comment: Чет не получаем у меня багу воспроизвести. Я кликаю по документу, поле поиска скрывается)

Comment: Там фишка в том, что если до того как поле открылось кликнуть по документ и в течении секунды сразу кликнуть на поиск, анимация заглючивает и поле поиска не открывается ,а меню не прячется.

Comment: А можете добавить код стилей или воспроизвести полностью где-то, чтоб можно было покликать)

Comment: Вот короче в архив кинул http://mega.dp.ua/file?source=18102418113516284235  Там фишка в чём ,код закрытия срабатывает при каждом клике на веб-документе, он там около полторы секунды выполняется и если пока он выполняется кликнуть еще на кнопку поиска получается баг как на третьем скрине.

Comment: В общем сделал через if                                                                 $(document).mouseup(function (e){ ...                                                                   if ( $('.menu_search').hasClass('menu_search-active')){ ..... } }                          Теперь скрипт закрытия срабатывает только если открыто меню поиска,а не при каждом клике на странице.

Comment: Не добрался чтоб посмотреть) Молодец что разобрался)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем сделал через if $(document).mouseup(function (e){ ... if ( $('.menu_search').hasClass('menu_search-active')){ ..... } } Теперь скрипт закрытия срабатывает только если открыто меню поиска,а не при каждом клике на странице.